# How to list all images from firebase in realtime into my reactjs web app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

constructor(props) {
        super(props);

```
    this.state = {
        arrayIMGS: arrayIMG,
        news: []

    };

}
```

componentDidMount() {
        var that = this

```
    firebase.database().ref('/IMAHE').on("child_added", function (dataNew) {
        let newData = [...that.state.arrayIMGS]

        newData.push(dataNew.val().createdAt, dataNew.val().url)
        alert("DIDMOUNT: "+dataNew.val().url)
        // alert(newData.values())

        that.setState({ news: dataNew.val().url })
    })
}
```

render() {

```
    var  data = [this.state.news]

    return(
        <div>
            <div style={headStyle}>

                <div style={perDivStyle}>


                    {data.map((e, idx) =>

                        <ListGroup>
                            <ListGroupItem key={idx}>
                                <Card>
                                    <CardImg top width="50%" src={e} alt="Card image cap" />
                                    <CardBody>
                                        <CardTitle>Card Title</CardTitle>
                                        <CardText>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</CardText>
                                        <CardText>
                                            <small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                                        </CardText>
                                    </CardBody>
                                </Card>
                            </ListGroupItem>
                        </ListGroup>



                    )}

                </div>

                <div style={footer}>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

export default Feed;

I'm making a reactjs app that provides a user the ability to upload images to firebase. All the uploaded image is expected to show up in a list of cards. What should I do to do this?

Comment: provide code please

Comment: I forgot @Omar sorry hehehe

Comment: call firebase and get new image once its uploaded.

Comment: this is my code for getting image url in firebase, the problem is that I only manage to render one image, but when I put it in alert() it fetched all the url of my images